# UISearchBar stays visible after scrolling

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I created a `TableView` and added a `UISearchBar` from the storyboard.

The `UISearchBarContoller` didn't work for me so I decided to use the `IBOutlet` method.

The problem is when I'm scrolling down, the search bar goes up and gets behind the segment controller.

I couldn't find any questions about this or any fixes on the internet related to the `IBOutlet` and not the `UISearchContoller`.

Is there any way to make it collapse?

I know I can take it out of the `TableView`, but I want it to collapse into itself when scrolling.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you add segment view? in the navigation bar?

Comment: In order to help solve a specific issue, we'll need more information. What does your code/storyboard look like?

Comment: The segment control is bellow the navigation bar using the repo SJSegmentedContorller.
It's a UIView that inherit from the SJ library.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how your storyboard or code is set up so I can only give guidelines. 
A few guesses:

1. It seems that you've set up the searchBar as a cell of the tableview since it scrolls with the content. Try setting it out either outside (above) the tableView or as header (see answer 2)
2. If you've set it up as the tableHeaderView you need to be wary of the fact that `UITableViewStylePlain` will keep it at the top, but `UITableViewStyleGrouped` will not.